# Does `ifconfig` show the MAC address of a network interface following `ether`?

Tags: ifconfig, mac-address

Does `ifconfig` show the MAC address of a network interface following `ether`?

Does `ether` mean ethernet? How does it mean Mac address?

```
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:b1:aa:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 451  bytes 43572 (43.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 108  bytes 28182 (28.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.97  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 xx:xx:xx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:1f:02:b5:c3:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 697657  bytes 564556036 (564.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 374913  bytes 60332457 (60.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [the `ifconfig` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ifconfig.8.html#OPTIONS), in the section on setting options,

> Set the hardware address of this interface, if the device driver supports this operation.  The keyword must be followed by the name of the hardware class and the printable ASCII  equivalent  of  the  hardware  address.   Hardware
>                 classes currently supported include `ether` (Ethernet), `ax25` (AMPR AX.25), `ARCnet` and `netrom` (AMPR NET/ROM).

This also explains the output, *i.e.* `ifconfig` shows the current hardware address of the interface, with its hardware class. For Ethernet interfaces, the class is `ether` and the hardware address is the MAC address.

Comment: THanks. `wlx8` is a wifi network interface, not an ethernet interface. Is the hardware address of a wifi interface also a MAC address?

Comment: Wi-fi uses Ethernet frames at the link layer, and it uses MAC addresses in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Note that different implementations of `ifconfig` report data in different ways.

For the net-tools version typically found on Linux, the word `ether` is the *hardware class*, and the value following that is the hardware address.  Both of these can be changed with the `ifconfig hw` command:

```
   hw class address
          Set the hardware address of this interface, if the device driver
          supports  this  operation.   The keyword must be followed by the
          name of the hardware class and the printable ASCII equivalent of
          the  hardware  address.   Hardware  classes  currently supported
          include ether (Ethernet), ax25 (AMPR AX.25), ARCnet  and  netrom
          (AMPR NET/ROM).
```

For the "Ethernet" hardware class the address is the card's MAC address.